# Retrieving Facebook's user avatar - how to define dimensions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I noticed that Facebook's user avatar has `160x160px` by default.

1. Is there a way that I can have the same picture but in larger size (180x180 for example)?
2. What's the best approach to if I want to re-size it to 90x90?

Comment: Uou mean the profile image?

Comment: It’s all described in broad detail here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Comment: @Shadowfax That's right, the little picture when users are logged in. The link from CBroe did the trick, very detailed how to retrieve's FB picture. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=12345%2F%3Ffields%3Dpicture.height%2890%29.width%2890%29) (graph api example: 12345/?fields=picture.height(90).width(90)).

You can also define the "type" (small, normal, large, square).